# Bootstrap tree-view: Tree doesn't show up

Tags: bootstrap-treeview

I'm new to tree-view, I'm trying to show a basic tree but it doesn't work and I don't know where I made the mistake.

I made test.html that follow the same structure of my basic.html (I'm sparing you code of the navbar, alerts, etc). I have other js functions in functions.js that work fine.

test.html:

```
{% csrf_token %}
{% load groupfilter %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap-treeview.min.css' %}">
       <script src="{% static 'bootstrap-treeview.min.js' %}"></script>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Test</title>
   </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="tree"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- JavaScript functions -->
            <script src="{% static 'functions.js' %}"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

extract of functions.js:

```
$(function(){
    var mytree = [
        {
            text: "Parent 1",
            nodes: [
                {
                    text: "Child 1",
                    nodes: [
                        {
                            text: "Grandchild 1"
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Grandchild 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: "Child 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: "Parent 2"
        }
    ];

    $('#tree').treeview({data: mytree});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share sample link that you are following?

It seems like you are importing Twitter Bootstrap 4.3.1

But as I know, Offical Bootstrap still not provide TreeView on their document.

Comment: Well, I'm following the tree-view doc (https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview), with the simple tree example. And yes I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1. This may be the reason why it doesn't work...

Comment: Where provided these are the actual versions bootstrap-treeview has been tested against.

Bootstrap v3.3.4 (>= 3.0.0)
jQuery v2.1.3 (>= 1.9.0)

Comment: @saikuron I see it is written down in Readme file. Just try again with same environment. Cheers! P.s: another way that let folk that repo then try to change version of Bootstrap and jQuery of it. Maybe still work on 4.3.1